# How super is implemented in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, jvm, superclass, super

Where the "super" is actually defined? [When we're using super.someMethod()]. Is it defined as a field in java.lang.Object class or java.lang.Class class?

When we're calling from a subclass, super contains the reference to it's superclass.In the same manner the super in superclass itself has reference to it's superclass [In this way upto java.lang.Object]. So, how java injects the superclass references to the "super" field which enables us to call superclass methods ?

Is there any under the hood implementaations like the following:

```
    Class current = this.getClass();
    Class parent = current.getSuperclass();
    System.out.println("name is =" + parent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super` is an object-reference specific keyword that ascends the object hierarchy beginning from the calling object until it finds an ancestor object that has a matching method signature or property/field. Refer to [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

Answer (score 15):

`super` like `this` is a keyword.  It has a meaning in Java which is not reflected in the Java byte code.  It means my parent classes' implementation (which could be inherited)

At the byte code level it will call the method for its parent class explicitly.

Comment: +1 I second this. In byte code it's no different to a standard method call.

Comment: You are right, to the extent that it is possible at the bytecode level to violate rules which the compiler enforces and call super() not as the first thing in a constructor. You can modify the bytecode to do this and the JVM will happily run it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a field - it's a [language keyword](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.11.2).

There is a reference to the superclass at the JVM level, of course, but on the Java level you can only access it through the keyword. The difference is that you could not in fact access a superclass method through a reference - it takes special support from the compiler to do that. And of course there is no `super.super`

Answer (score 1):

> Is it defines as a field in java.lang.Object class or java.lang.Class class?

It is not a field at all.

`super.someMethod()` is a Java syntactic element that says "call the method as defined in my superclass".

---

OK, suppose that hypothetically it *was* a field.  What would its type be?  What would it refer to?  If it was declared as:

```
Class<ParentClass> super = ... // the relevant class object.
```

then `super.someMethod()` wouldn't work because:

- `Class` doesn't have any user-defined methods, and
- `super.someMethod()` needs to be a call to an instance method, and we are not supplying a suitable instance.

On the other hand if it was declared as:

```
ParentClass super = this;
```

then `super.someMethod()` would be equivalent to `this.someMethod()` and would call the method in this class, not the overridden on.

Comment: Is there any chance that getSuperClass() method of class java.lang.Class are being used [i.e.  maybe java reflection is being used under the hood to inject reference ]                                                           http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass%28%29

Comment: No.  There is no chance that is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will start climbing the ancestors chain until it finds the first class that has the method you put following super. Seems the easiest way. This is done at compile time if you think about it. In the end a method is just a function pointer, with an invokation method that accepts the instance in question (in your case it is `this`). Look the [Method.invoke](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)  documentation

It will be used by the compiler with a Method instance from the super class and this as the Object instance

Comment: It always calls the direct super class so no "climbing" involved. But obviously a class inherits all public/protected methods of its parent, so the difference is mostly splitting hairs (you notice the difference when trying to call constructors per super and wrt overload resolution though)

Comment: conceptually it is like you say. But practically the code is not repeated, the sub-classes will just have pointers to the super class compiled methods. I was meaning that, because he was more interested in the implementation.